# Can I make sqlite3 inserts fast safely?

Tags: performance, insert, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 to store some data on a raspberry pi application. With the default settings an insert takes about 2.6 seconds. This is way too slow for my application. I am trying to speed it up. I am doing inserts or updates fairly regularly (every couple seconds) and power can be yanked from the Pi an any time. It's totally fine if i lost that last update or even last several updates but I don't want to risk corrupting the entire database. I have read that setting synchronous=OFF can cause corruption. Is there an alternative that will speed it up without risking corruption of the entire db?

Comment: @HotLicks Please make that an answer.

Comment: Im just doing one insert at a time. Not a lot of inserts.

Comment: @HotLicks, Thank you for you condescending response. I have read the documentation. I've read all about transactions and the synchronous setting and journal_mode, etc, but none of those solutions seem to fit. If I am doing periodic inserts every couple seconds, when would I end the transaction? If power is pulled before ending the transaction I still risk corruption. Also, I am hoping to use ActiveRecord eventually and then I don't think I have any control over when transactions are began/ended (not sure on that though).